# How to make progress bar to represent chunk download by http range header using multi threading in android?

Tags: android

I'm downloading a file from URL using HttpUrlConnection and dividing large file into small parts and downloading it using multi threading in android.

So, the question is how to make a progress representation for each small parts simultaneously into one single progress bar?

Like the representation of segment downloading progress in Internet Download Manager.

Answer (score 0):

your request can be done with some math , let say you have five parts , so each part will represent 100 / 5 = 20 % of the main `ProgressBar` ,

```
int step = 100 / 5 ;
int value = 0 ;
```

as soon as one part is complete you set your new value

```
 value = value + step
 progressBar.setProgress(value)
```

hope it helps